# How to use the inbuilt 3G modem of my laptop?

Tags: windows, laptop, hsdpa

I have a laptop - Dell Adamo Onyx. It's with Win7 (64bit). Yesterday I bought a Huawei E173 HSPA usb stick with a plan. All works fine, but how can I use the sim card directly from my laptop, without the modem? I think it has 3G support (or it's GPS only?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the specs I found [here](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/laptops/270979/dell-adamo-admire-onyx/specifications) I would say it doesn't have a build-in 3G slot.

If unsure, check the slot where the battery is. Most laptops that are 3G enabled have a SIM slot there.

To verify, check the owners manual if there is anything about a SIM slot.

Comment: It has a sim slot, I putted my card there, but it had no reaction.

Comment: Any unknown devices inside *Device Manager*? If not, and there is no sign of an 3G device I would think this is only the slot - but no electronic behind.

Comment: No unknown devices, only: BRoadcom NetLink Gigabit Ethernet, Intel WiFi Link 5300 AGN in network adapters and: Dell Wireless GPS/WPS Virtual Com Port (COM3) on Ports

Comment: Well, then you need to stick with the USB stick. Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought it has HSPA support.

Comment: @blez - The Adamo "Admire" doesn't have 3G, but the "Desire" model does.  Both will probably have the Sim slot, it just that the Admire won't work (no actual 3G modem).  Which do you have?

Comment: The Intel SL9600 2.13Ghz 4GB RAM model.

Comment: This should be the Desire model.

Comment: @techie007: If it has 3G modem, how to check it? And ofcourse how to use it?

Comment: @blez - I have a 3G modem in my hand-held W7 PC.  It came with 3rd party software for controlling the 3G (connecting, usage tracking, etc.), but since I upgraded it to Windows 7 (from XP) Windows can now handle the connection like any other modem connection. The 3G shows up in the "Modem" section of the Device Manager, as well as a couple COM ports.  Ensure it's enabled in your BIOS, and perhaps check with Dell for software to control/enable it.

Comment: @techie007: In the BIOS all is enabled and I have "Control WWAN". I installed the Dell Mobile Broadband Manager, but it still says "The mobile broadband device is not found.". Also in Device Manager I don't see any "Modem" section.

Comment: @blez - Unfortunately I think you'll probably have to consult with the place of purchase, or Dell, to determine exactly which options your model has before we can help much more.

Comment: Actually I bought it from ebay.